# How to give space for each bar in achartengine bar chart?

Tags: android, achartengine

I am working on android. I searched some links in google regarding bar charts and tried them. It is working well. I have some doubt in it.

[image]

My code:

```
package in.wptrafficanalyzer.achartenginebarchart;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.chart.BarChart.Type;
import org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
import org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries;
import org.achartengine.model.MultipleCategorySeries;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.model.XYSeries;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String[] mMonth = new String[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May",
            "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Getting reference to the button btn_chart
        Button btnChart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_chart);

        // Defining click event listener for the button btn_chart
        OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Draw the Income vs Expense Chart
                openChart();
            }
        };

        // Setting event click listener for the button btn_chart of the
        // MainActivity layout
        btnChart.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

    }

    private void openChart() {
        int[] x = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
        int[] income = { 2000, 2500, 2700, 3000, 2800, 3500, 3700, 3800 };
        // int[] expense = {2200, 2700, 2900, 2800, 2600, 3000, 3300, 3400 };

        // Creating an XYSeries for Income
        // CategorySeries incomeSeries = new CategorySeries("Income");
        XYSeries incomeSeries = new XYSeries("Income");
        // Creating an XYSeries for Income
        // XYSeries expenseSeries = new XYSeries("Expense");
        // Adding data to Income and Expense Series
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            incomeSeries.add(i, income[i]);
            // expenseSeries.add(i,expense[i]);
        }

        // Creating a dataset to hold each series
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        // Adding Income Series to the dataset
        dataset.addSeries(incomeSeries);
        // Adding Expense Series to dataset
        // dataset.addSeries(expenseSeries);

        // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize incomeSeries
        XYSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        incomeRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(130, 130, 230));
        incomeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
        incomeRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
        incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

        // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize expenseSeries
        // XYSeriesRenderer expenseRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        // expenseRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(220, 80, 80));
        // expenseRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
        // expenseRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
        // expenseRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

        // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Income vs Expense Chart");
        multiRenderer.setXTitle("Year 2012");
        multiRenderer.setYTitle("Amount in Dollars");
        multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, mMonth[i]);
        }

        // Adding incomeRenderer and expenseRenderer to multipleRenderer
        // Note: The order of adding dataseries to dataset and renderers to
        // multipleRenderer
        // should be same
        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(incomeRenderer);
        // multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(expenseRenderer);

        // Creating an intent to plot bar chart using dataset and
        // multipleRenderer
        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(getBaseContext(),
                dataset, multiRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);

        // Start Activity
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Actually I want to make the chart look like individual bars but here all the bars are combined. How can I separate to individual bars via code.
Please help me regarding this. Will be really thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer following links : it may help you 
http://moinur-rahman.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-plot-charts-and-graphs-for.html
http://aspnetgeek.wordpress.com/2011/09/09/graphs-on-android-using-achartengine/

Answer (score 7):

Use barSpacing option as follows

```
multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(1);
```